# How to set up application menu in electron?

Tags: menu, electron

if i start the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start) application, i get a full OSX menu:

[image]

I then add this code, mostly copied from docs, to my main.js:

```
const Menu = require('menu');                                                                                                                                                                            
const MenuItem = require('menu-item');
var mainmenu = new Menu();
mainmenu.append(new MenuItem({ label: 'MenuItem1', click: function() { console.log('item 1 clicked'); } }));
Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainmenu);
```

I also tried to use menu template code from the [electron menu docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/30d815e28f0bf0215da9e5a0e85de280a86b5cc9/docs/api/menu.md), with the exact same disappointing result:

[image]

I also tried to add the code above to index.html, literally copying the code on Menu's doc. Same thing.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You want to change the "Electron" menu? Is this a packaged app? if it's not, have you tried the setName method `app.setName('YOURAPPNAME')`?

Comment: @Philip i did. it works for subsequent app.getName() calls, but the menu will always have Electron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`electron-prebuilt` that it's used on the `electron-quick-start` example has it's own app name (Electron).

To change this you need to rebuild/package your app and it will use the "name" or "productName" from your package.json.

Also there is method to set/get the app name but you have to package your app to see that change on the main menu:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;

app.setName('APPNAME');
```

Comment: the setName work around did not work while using prebuilt package.

Comment: If you are using the `electron-prebuilt` package you can't change the `appName`. You need to rebuild/package your app and it will use the `name/productName` values from your `package.json`. I suggest you to try the `electron-packager` here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager